# Slice a pandas dataframe without delimiter

Tags: python

I have a `csv` file with 580 thousands lines and one column that no has delimiter. It's a unique one line of data (e.g. 012018010202AALR3       010ALLIAR      ON      NM   R$  000000000149400000000015160000000001470000000000148400000000014890000000001475000000000148900403000000000000094500000000000140299100000000000000009999123100000010000000000000BRAALRACNOR6100)

I need to slice the start, end and numbers of characters for each information that I want to extract.

I have the layout e.g.(date start: positon 3 end: position 10 number of characters =8)

So, What I need is something like this:

```
date=slice(start:3, end:10 , characters : 8)
```

return = : `20180102`

Thanks

I'm using jupyter notebook and pandas

I use this code but didn't work:

```
bova_txt["data"]= bova_txt["serie"].str.slice(2,10, 8)
```

I'm getting this:

```
0         2
1         2
2         2
3         2
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

Comment: Pandas series.str.slice() isn't `(start, stop, num_chars)`, it (like all python slicing) is `(start, stop, step)`. So you've told it to start at character 2, end at (before) character 10, and do a step of 8...which means only return the character at position `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from a comment:

[Pandas series.str.slice()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) isn't (start, stop, num_chars), as the number of characters is implicit in the start and stop. It (like all python slicing) is (start, stop, step). You are telling the code to give you the 2nd, 10th, 18th, etc character in a substring of length `8`.

If you leave out the third arg, the step, your code works fine as-is on the test line you provided

```
bova_txt["data"].str.slice(2,10)
0    20180102
```

Comment: Thanks, It's worked perfectly. I read the documentation but I didn't understand the option "step". With the explanation I understood.